# Setting file path and organizing the code in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Hi I have following module, route and controller defined in one file called main.js

```
   var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ui"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/addEmp', { controller: EmpCtrl, templateUrl: 'addEmp.html' }).
            when('/addLoc', { controller: LocCtrl, templateUrl: 'newLocation.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });



mainApp.factory("addEmp", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/addEmp/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
}]);

mainApp.factory("addLoc", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/newLoc/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
}]);


//Controllers 
var EmpCtrl = function ($scope, $location, addEmp) {

   //code here 
};

var LocCtrl = function ($scope, $location, newLocation) {

   //code here 
};
```

What I am trying to do is organize this one file code into different files. I created script/controller   folder where I want to have individual files for controller like
EmpCtrl.js and LocCtrl.js.
When I created the controller files and copied the controller code in it i get error of EmptCtrl and LocCtrl not defined. 
Can you please tell me how I can set it up in different folders with appropriate path settings? 
Thanks

Comment: Add EmpCtrl.js and LocCtrl.js to script tags

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  angular.module("mainApp", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ui"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/addEmp', { controller: 'empCtrl', templateUrl: 'addEmp.html' }).
            when('/addLoc', { controller: 'locCtrl', templateUrl: 'newLocation.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });



    //in empCtrl.js file
    angular.module('mainApp').controller('empCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'addEmp',
        function ($scope, $location, addEmp) {
        //code here 
    }]);

    // same for locCtrl
```

In your html make sure to include your mainApp.js file before you empCtrl and locCtrl scripts
 the key is that you use string names to refer to your controller in your rout configs

```
    { controller: 'empCtrl' ... }
```

instead of

```
    { controller: EmpCtrl ... }
```

I would recommend that you use require.js to modularize your Angular project, you won't have to worry about order of script includes and it will result in a cleaner project